# Custom meta box not working on Blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

Welcome, I created custom meta box from this [tutorial](http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/comment-page-4/), but If I set in WordPress

`Page of entries > Blog - page`

my `$my_meta['name']` and `$my_meta['description']` are taken from the last blog entry not from My custom meta box ;/

What should I do to get name and description from My custom meta box on Blog page ? On another pages  it works perfectly, Thank you for your for answers

Answer (score 1):

This will get the ID of the page instead of the last post (for the page set as Posts page in Settings -> Reading):

```
//get page id even for posts page
global $wp_query;
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`get_post_meta();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function. It returns the values of the custom fields with the specified key from the specified post.

```
//Inside your Blog page Loop. 'meta_key' is the key of your custom field. Do the same for each custom field. Please take a look in the Codex  from the above link.
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key', true );
```

I could be wrong, since there are no other clues in the question.

Hope it helps!